# How to implement Memcached with PDO

Tags: php, memcached, pdo

Do I have to modify every single query in my application in order to use Memcached?

I am using this DB class from a PDO tutorial:

```
class DB {

private static $host;
private static $dbName;
private static $user;
private static $password;

/*** Declare instance ***/
private static $instance = NULL;

/**
*
* the constructor is set to private so
* so nobody can create a new instance using new
*
*/
private function __construct() {}

/**
*
* Return DB instance or create intitial connection
* @return object (PDO)
* @access public
*
*/
public static function getInstance() {

    if (!self::$instance){
        self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=".self::$host.";dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$user, self::$password);
        self::$instance-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

/**
*
* Like the constructor, we make __clone private
* so nobody can clone the instance
*
*/
private function __clone(){}

} /*** end of class ***/
```

Is there a nice easy way of modifying it to incorporate Memcached?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How i can design a cache system using PDO and memcached?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600720/how-i-can-design-a-cache-system-using-pdo-and-memcached)

Comment: @Robert I read that question and its link, none of which helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firstly I would re structure your class to extend the PDO Class like so:

```
class Database extends PDO
{
    /**
    *
    * the constructor is set to private so
    * so nobody can create a new instance using new
    *
    */
    private static $Instance;
    public $Cache = null;

    public function Instance()
    {
        if(self::$Instance === null)
        {
            self::$Instance = new Database;
            self::$Instance->Cache = new Memcached;
        }
        return self::$Instance;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct("Connection;String");
         $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('DBStatement', array(&$this)));
    }
}
```

---

```
class DBStatement extends PDOStatement
{
    public $db;

    protected function __construct(&$db)
    {
        $this->db =& $db;
    }
    /*
         * PDO Methods!
     */

    public function rowCount()
    {
        return $this->foundRows;
    }

    public function execute($array = null)
    {
        if ($array === null)
        {
            $result = parent::execute();
        }else
        {
            $result = parent :: execute($array);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then the the methods would be overridden as the example in the above class DBStatement, with execute.

Each method that returns an a set of results you would them md5 the query to create a unique hash for that query, you would then check to see if it exists in the cache, if so you would return instead, otherwise just run a new query fetching the results, and then before you return them, store them within the cache

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not quite getting why it needs a separate rowCount function, or how to properly integrate the caching into the PDO Statement. The PDO Statement object is returned by the PDO, so would the cache stuff not have to be in the class that extends PDO rather than the Statement?

Comment: Well even as the PODStatement is returned by PDO Main, its still not executed against the server, when you run the execute on the statement thats when you should be checking for a cached version of the data.