# Where to instantiate new Memcache in a php mvc

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo, memcached

I'm trying to get my caching working correctly so that I don't need to create a new instance of memcache every time I want to cache a query in a model function:

```
class contentModel {

    function getData() {

        $core = Connect::getInstance();

        $memcache = new Memcache;
        $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

        $data = $memcache->get("query".$sql);

        if($!data)
            // get data

        return $data;
    }
}
```

If in my root index.php I add:

```
global $memcache;
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

Then would I just be able to call `$memcache->get($key)` throughout all classes without have to re instance it?

Or is there another way I should go about simplifying this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `$memcached` a static member of your model base class, for example:

```
class Model {
    protected static $memcached;

    public static function setMemcached(Memcached $mc) {
        self::$memcached = $mc;
    }
}

class User extends Model {
    public function getData() {
        parent::$memcached->get("...");
    }
}

// In index.php
Model::setMemcached(new Memcached("127.0.0.1:11211"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the caching be better implemented in a database/data access library and then optionally invoked for particular queries/data requests? That way the actual mechanism used to perform the caching would be transparent to the models.

You would only have to maintain a single instance in the database library which would be shared. There would be a performance hit to check whether to use caching or not, but it's relatively cheap compared to the increased complexity in all of your models.

Comment: yes that could be possible but I'm not sure how to do that with pdo queries?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600720/how-i-can-design-a-cache-system-using-pdo-and-memcached

Comment: Well I get that bit, it's more the dynamically binding parameters to keep the queries secure within one function that's the tricky bit.

Comment: Do you mean generating unique keys? Knowing both the query and parameters means you can generate a unique key from them surely, or at the very least pass an optional custom key as part of the data access call? There's a nice memcache implementation in the [phpactiverecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) library that you could perhaps look at for inspiration  - it implements a Cache class with memcache as an adapter. The data is passed using a closure in this case (so PHP 5.3), along with a key which you would be responsible for generating.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you have to think that accessing cache data is (again) accessing data, and that is a responsability to be handled by your Data Access Objects (or models, or whatever you wanna call them).

Because, if not, what are you going to do? provide access to memcached from the view makes no sense at all, and the controllers? well the controllers should take care of managing form information and so, but as a controller must not access the database it should not either access memcached.

Finally, if you manage your memcached on the models/daos, you have a SINGLE point of writing/reading to/from memcached, so you can safely know that cache information always reflects db information. Also it will be totally transparent for the developer (specially useful in medium-large teams). Also, by having a centralized (again, model/dao) place to access memcached, you will avoid to have different keys storing the same value, hence you will save memory and will be able to cache more info.

Comment: My Memcache is currently in the model, but the problem is it's in every single function so there's a lot of code being repeated that I know doesn't need to be, I need help working out where memcache should go to reduce this redundant code.